# How to keep aero glass when handling WM_NCPAINT WinEvent

Tags: c++, qt, button, dwm, nonclient-area

I’m handling the WM_NCPAINT WinEvent for draw a pushbutton at the non client area of my window. But as you can see at the following image, the aero glass border has disappeared, and my window has no border. So I've found this answer: [Handling WM_NCPAINT "breaks" DWM glass rendering on Vista/Aero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146365/handling-wm-ncpaint-breaks-dwm-glass-rendering-on-vista-aero) and I’ve tried to apply the solution proposed on that page on my project with no result. What I’m doing wrong?

Screenshot of my window:

[image]

On my .pro file I’ve added:

```
LIBS += -lGdi32
LIBS += -lUser32
LIBS += -lDwmApi
LIBS += -lUxTheme
```

And here my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>
#include <tmschema.h>
#include <Strsafe.h>
#include <limits.h>

HTHEME m_htheme;

bool MainWindow::winEvent(MSG *pMessage, long *result)
{
    UINT m = pMessage->message;
    if(m == WM_NCPAINT || m == WM_ACTIVATE)
    {
        draw();
        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::winEvent(pMessage, result);
}

void MainWindow::draw()
{
    HWND id = winId();

    DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY policy = DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
    HRESULT hr = DwmSetWindowAttribute(id, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, (void*)&policy, sizeof(DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY));

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        m_htheme = OpenThemeData(id, L"Button");
        if (m_htheme)
        {
            HDC hDeviceContext = GetWindowDC(id);
            RECT rc = {10, 10, 100, 32};
            RECT rcContent;

            LPCWSTR caption = TEXT("text");
            size_t cch;
            StringCchLength(caption, MAX_PATH, &cch);

            hr = DrawThemeBackground(m_htheme, hDeviceContext, BP_PUSHBUTTON, CBS_NORMAL, &rc, 0);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                hr = GetThemeBackgroundContentRect(m_htheme, hDeviceContext, BP_PUSHBUTTON,
                                                   CBS_NORMAL, &rc, &rcContent);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                hr = DrawThemeText(m_htheme, hDeviceContext, BP_PUSHBUTTON, CBS_NORMAL,
                                   caption, cch, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE, 0, &rcContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Qt, but I would imagine `DefWindowProc` is not getting called and should be.

Comment: @chris how do you think it should be used?

Comment: I haven't worked with this much, but calling `DefWindowProc`, then rendering your button should work. I have no clue if there's a better way.

Comment: @chris Calling `DefwindowProc` is the typical starting point. `DrawFrameControl` and `DrawCaption` can also be used to render various parts of the non-client area such as menus, captions bars and scrollbars.

Comment: By calling `DefWindowProc(id, m, NULL, NULL);` inside the WM_NCPAINT event, enables the aero interface, but not enable glass, how can i enable it?

Comment: Update: With `DefWindowProc(pMessage->hwnd, pMessage->message, pMessage->wParam, pMessage->lParam);` the glass is established, but the button stays behind the window.